# Cell Variable in google sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a couple filtering formulas in Google sheet and would like edit them with another variable.

The filter is for example (it shows all non empty cells form a row):

```
=FILTER('Data Input'!$A$3:$A$9781; NOT(ISBLANK('Data Input'!$X$3:$X$9781)))
```

The X should be a variable that I can set from a different cell. I was trying stuff like `INDEX`

```
=FILTER('Data Input'!$A$3:$A$9781; NOT(ISBLANK('Data Input'!$INDEX(I13)$3:$INDEX(I13)$9781)))
```

but this just returns an error. Does anyone know how I can pass cell reference variables in a filter function?

Comment: Try to replace `$INDEX(I13)$3` with `Indirect(I13&3)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Aneta ! I didn't realize you need to add rows and columns for it to work

Comment: We are not adding them, I assume that in the cell `I13` you have a letter of a column you want to use and I am joining it with the number `3` to create a string. The string will be turned into a cell reference by the `indirect` formula.

Comment: Ok, this works for me: `=FILTER('Data Input'!$A$3:$A$9781; NICHT(ISTLEER(INDIREKT($I2))))` and in I2 i have written: `''Data Input'!$V$3:$V$9781`  (Note the double single quotes at the beginning. Otherwise gsheets omits the single one)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure, but I believe you're looking for `OFFSET` rather than `INDEX`. `OFFSET` will allow you to enter integers in a cell which you would reference in your filter formula. Those integers would allow you to adjust which column you're using to check for NOT(ISBLANK...) which is what it looks like you're trying to do.

Maybe this will work, `I13` will have the value of the column index (Column X = 24)

`NOT(ISBLANK(OFFSET($A$1,2,$I$13-1):OFFSET($A$1,9780,$I$13-1))`

`OFFSET($A$1,2,$I$13-1):OFFSET($A$1,9780,$I$13-1)` Should evaluate to `$X$3:$X$9781` while `I13 = 24`